# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index (when migrating from iBATIS to MyBatis)

Tags: migration, mybatis, ibatis, wildfly-10

Faced this problem when migrating the application from iBATIS to MyBatis

> org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='userDefRole', mode=null, javaType=class java.lang.String, jdbcType=VARCHAR, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType VARCHAR . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

Parameter Mapping

```
<parameterMap type="userDefVO" id="userDefVO">

        <parameter property="userDefRole" javaType="string"
            jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
        <parameter property="userShortRole" javaType="string"
            jdbcType="VARCHAR"  />
        <parameter property="userDefRoleDesc" javaType="string"
            jdbcType="VARCHAR"  />
        <parameter property="sysRole" javaType="string"
            jdbcType="VARCHAR"  />

    </parameterMap>
```

This is my select query

```
<select id="fetchUserDefRole" resultMap="defRoleVO"
        parameterMap="userDefVO">
        SELECT * FROM PARTY_ROLE_SETUP 
        <where>

            <if test='userDefRole != null and userDefRole != "" '>

                and USER_DEF_ROLE like '%' || #{userDefRole} || '%'

            </if>
            <if test='userShortRole != null and userShortRole != "" '>

                and USER_SHORT_ROLE = #{userShortRole}

            </if>
            <if test='userDefRoleDesc != null and userDefRoleDesc != "" '>

                and USER_DEF_ROLE_DESC like '%' || #{userDefRoleDesc} || '%'

            </if>
            <if test='sysRole != null and sysRole != "" '>

                and SYSTEM_ROLE  = #{sysRole}

            </if>

        </where>

    </select>
```

This is DB table

```
USER_DEF_ROLE      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)  
USER_SHORT_ROLE             VARCHAR2(10)  
USER_DEF_ROLE_DESC          VARCHAR2(120) 
SYSTEM_ROLE                 VARCHAR2(10)
```

Please help me in knowing what is wrong in this code and what is causing invalid column index exception

Comment: Try it without the parameterMap. parameterMap is deprecated in mybatis. Also what version of mybatis are you using?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. Yes, using parameterType resolved the problem, Im using 3.4.4 mybatis version

Comment: Ok glad it works. You can remove parameterMap for any other mappers you port to MyBatis